# How to get the lines between two specific lines [multiples times] in Windows Batch file from multiples files.txt

Tags: batch

Need to extract contents between two lines from text file.

Base on research on similar questions:
[Batch Script To Extract Lines Between Two Specified Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069790/batch-script-to-extract-lines-between-two-specified-lines)

A sample script is made

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion


for %%F in (*.txt) do (

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "----"^<%%F') do set /a start=%%a
for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n "========="^<%%F') do set /a end=%%a
for /f "tokens=1* delims=[]" %%a in ('find /n /v ""^<%%F') do (
  if %%a geq !start! if %%a leq !end! echo(%%b
 )
```

The script is able to set variables start and end, but the last
`if` statement fail to evaluate them even with `!` in my `!variables!`.

Content of text file:

```
line   one
line   two ----------------
line three  Needed content
line  four  Needed content
line  five ================
line   six
line seven ----------------
line eight  Needed content
line  nine  Needed content
line   ten ================
line   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

- For one file:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "_line=0" & for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "Z:\SU_2022\Q1720596\Some File Text.txt"
    ')do if "!_line!" == "0" (echo;"%%~i"| findstr /c:"----" >nul && set "_line=1" )else (
         echo\"%%~i" | findstr /c:"====" >nul && set "_line=0" || (set /p "'=%%~i" <nul & echo\))
         
endlocal
```

---

- Content of my test file: `Z:\SU_2022\Q1720596\Some File Text.txt"`

```bat
What is Lorem Ipsum?
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into 
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in 
===============================================================================
the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, 
and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. 
===============================================================================
Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, 
looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum 
passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered 
the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of 
de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the 
Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes 
from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 
===============================================================================
1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 
from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact 
original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.

Why do we use it?
It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content 
of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a 
more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content
here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page
editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
===============================================================================
years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
```

- Output results echoing:

```bat
specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in
in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the
Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes
from a line in section 1.10.32.The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the
will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
```

---

- For multiples files:

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%G in (*.txt)do set "_line=0" & for /f "delims=" %%i in (
    'type "%%~G"')do if "!_line!" == "0" (echo;"%%~i"| findstr /c:"----" >nul && set "_line=1"
        )else (echo\"%%~i" | findstr /c:"====" >nul && set "_line=0" || (set /p "'=%%~i" <nul & echo\))
         
endlocal
```

---

> *On screen. Need the source text filename show as*
> *a prefix in the same line of string output.*

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%G in (*.txt)do set /p "'=%%~nxG" <nul & echo/ & set "_line=0" & for /f "delims=" %%i in (
    'type "%%~G"')do if "!_line!" == "0" (echo;"%%~i" | findstr /c:"----" >nul && set "_line=1"
        )else (echo\"%%~i" | findstr /c:"====" >nul && set "_line=0" || (set /p "'=%%~i" <nul & echo\))
         
endlocal
```

---

**Obs.:** It has [multiple variations of "`-`"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), try to copy the character of the file and paste in: `findstr /c:"----"`

---

**Additional resources:**

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [`Echo /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)
- [`Finstr /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [`For /F /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

  - [`For /F commands`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.
- [`Local Environment | Function`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html)

  - [`Setlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-functions.html) & [`Endlocal`](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [`If Condition() Else If Condition() Else()`](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter [`cmd.exe`] Parse Scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/6819406)

Comment: Thanks for response. Actually, I need to process many text files and the needed lines are different among the text files. But the needed contents are bounded by line with "----------" and "========". Thats why my oiginal script simply check the line index. I found the problem due to IF statement can handle non-variable with operator  like "if !var! geq 4" but not "if !var! lss !var2!"...

Comment: Many thanks. It is working fine. For multiple text version, could file name be included at the start of content like: File1.txt needed contents

Comment: On screen or in the output file?

Comment: On screen. Need the source text filename show as a prefix in the same line of string output.

Comment: See my last edit... is this?